# Is it evil to link to a crontab?

Tags: security, cron, symlink, home

I think about doing something like:

```
sudo ln -s ~/myCustomCrontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username
```

because I'd like to have all customized files in my home directory. Possible risks I can think of are

- security (How should the permissions be to still be secure?)
- system failure

Or is there a better way to "keep track of the file"?

Comment: If `/var/spool/cron` isn't readable by `username`, the softlink is useless as it can't be used by the user to access the actual crontab file anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The soft-link is in the other direction. The cronjob file /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username is replaced with a symlink to ~username/myCustomCrontab which is editable by the user.

Comment: @jofel Yeah, that won't work.  For a lot of reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This **does not work**, at least in Debian-like systems (symlinked or hardlinked crontab files for (not-system) users are [ignored at all](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/database.c#n354)).
It also fails if you use `crontab` to change your crontab file. If the cron version still accepts symlinked crontab files, it **creates possible security holes** as the crontab file is not checked anymore for consistency.

With your symlink solution, `crontab -e` crashes if you (or some install script) changes the crontab file:

```
crontab: crontabs/username: rename: Operation not permitted
```

as it moves a temporary file to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/username`
to replace the old file instantaneously.

crontab has a lot of additional security checks built in such that
the cron system cannot be used to compromise the system. It checks for example the content of the cron file before installing or changing it. A invalid cron
file may crash the `cron` daemon or could (at least theoretically) misuse it to gain more privileges on the system.
With your solution, there is no check anymore for the crontab file.

Comment: What OS?  I can't see how a softlink to a `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/username` can cause problems other than the normal ones caused by not using `crontab` to edit the file, which probably won't work anyway since `/var/spool/cron` usually is owned by `root` with `0700` permissions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle At least for Debian's `cron`, the crontabs for normal user in  `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` need to be regular files (see [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/database.c#n355)).

Answer (score 10):

**No!**

Don't do that!!

By all means have a copy of your `crontab` (and others) stored somewhere such as your home directory, but don't touch the system files.

```
crontab -l >my_crontab    # Start by getting current rules

vi my_crontab             # Edit my copy of the crontab file
crontab my_crontab        # Install it
```

(Personally, I use `$HOME/.crontab` for my per-user copy.)

A better way to track system files might be to create a source code repository (git, cvs, mercury, whatever) and use that to track your changes. A `Makefile` could be used to install changes into the relevant system directories and restart dependent services; in this scenario you'd simply type `sudo make install` and it would.

Comment: I would upvote both answers given so far, but I don't have voting privilege yet. Thanks for the `crontab my_crontab` hint, that's useful! I just always used `crontab -e`...

Comment: and before doing this backup your crontab. i just lost mine due to this.

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic that doesn't make sense. This whole answer talks about saving a copy of the `crontab` file outside of `cron`

Comment: @roaima yeah ofc and that's good but i didn't know `crontab my_crontab` would overwrite it immediatelly. my bad, so i just wanted to keep someone else from typing that command right away.

Comment: @FedjaM. Uh, it doesn't; it just reads the file.

Comment: @FedjaM. I even put a comment alongside the command, "_Install it_". What did you think this comment meant? (Maybe I can make it clearer)

Answer (score 1):

No need to link.
Just add a line to your wished crontab file (/home/user/my_crontab) that makes a daily install of itself.

```
58 23  *   *   *     crontab /home/user/my_crontab
00 12  *   *   *     bash /home/user/do-other things.
```

Kickstart process by installing it: `crontab /home/user/my_crontab`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this wont work on most systems because symbolic links aren't read by most CRON implementations.  Complicating matters, cron is one of the few system config files housed in /var.  Be aware that often custom files in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/<yourfilename>` are better substitutes to grabbing your file from /var. Moreover, your desire to have canonical sources   (even better if you version control them) is a good one. This allows you to use something like [etc keeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) to keep a version controlled backup.  But, like you, I like putting everything in one place (my configured `etc` and dotfiles in a single version-controlled folder in my home dir; makes reconfigs and restoring a lot easier) so I find etc keeper overkill when I only need less than 1% of the files.

Instead of constantly installing a new crontab at each CRON  run (now THAT is a security flaw if someone gets access to your user-owned file in home and adds something malicious elevated by root-level cron), I would copy the cron you have to your canonical directory at each run:

```
0 * * * * <username> cp /etc/cron.d/<your custom cronfile> /home/user/<where you want your backup>
```

Then as long as the system is on during one of these hourly runs (or just set it to a time your system is usually on), a backup will be stored to your version-controlled area.  When you want to update cron, you modify the source as root NOT your user-level backup.  Yeah it's not ideal perspective, but given the security requirements of CRON, it allows you to keep a canonical (version-controlled) source of config without backing up all or a small selection of etc in a more hacky way.

To your original question regarding the security:  if any of the files you're linking from `/etc` to your home canonical files is used by a process with elevated access to run commands (like CRON) this is a security risk (though probably not a huge one if you have no ports open, a firewall, and single-user system), because if anyone gets access to that file then they can run commands as root (probably why CRON doesn't allow symlinks).  If what you're storing is used only for read-level configuration (like, say, `/etc/fstab` it still could be a risk depending on the power and actions of the executing process, but less so.  But like you, I take that very small risk for a firewalled, no-service, single-user system to keep a tidy version-controlled backup in one place. In this case however, CRON isn't going to let you do this because many systems have a far greater attack surface than you or me.